# Constraints on dependent variable Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, differential-equations

I am working on a Simulation-Optimization routine in Matlab. Myprogram solves a set of [Differential Algebraic Equations (DAEs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebraic_equation) which depend on a set of design variables **x** and computes a cost function (objective function). The value of the objective function is passed to `fmincon`, which decides how to update **x**, so constraints are fulfilled.

I was wondering if there is a way to recursively impose bounds not only to **x**, but to internal variables. I have, for instance, a physical limitation on the area of a piece of equipment, but this value does not belong to **x**, (it is a dependent variable). I know that one can include penalty functions to the objective function to account for these variables, but I would want to know if there is a way to make this internal variables "visible" to the optimizer, so it runs according to bounds or inequality conditions on them.